# Can't apply css to bootstrap navbar

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add custom styles to navigation and body but the styles aren't showing in my home page but it's showing in another page I'm not getting it any one can help me out with solution where I'm messing around

index.php

```
<?php include 'include/css.php';?>
<?php $page = 'home';include 'include/navbar.php';?>

<?php include 'include/scripts.php';?>
```

[Screenshot of browser for index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/telh5.jpg)

css.php

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

[Screenshot of browser for /include/css.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57WMG.png)

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;!important
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

i am attaching github link please download files upload in your local server and 
 kindly find the error

[you can download files here](https://github.com/santosh81066/demo_styles_not_working/tree/fb87aed539e8012495357744b9e7825bba2f09ee)

Comment: I'd be looking at the generated HTML - In your browser - Right Click -> View Page Source ( or what is ever similar for your browser) and what do you see?

Comment: ya i had checked the source but my index.php is taking different path where as i am using include to import css.I am keeping include files in include folder where css.php files are included and i am calling stylesheet form outside include folder in css folder where as index.php is not talking path

Comment: i had also tried by keeping css folder inside the include folder  then also not working

Comment: Try  href="./css/style.css" with one dot, not two as the style.css is relative to the index.php is at the same level.

Comment: no it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
body{
   background-color: aqua !important;
}
.navbar-nav a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: styles are not working at all on index page for reference i will attach you the screen shots

Comment: Did you inclued your style file within head tag?

Comment: i had included css file in head tag

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have a path issue for `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">` 
check your directory for home page and other pages.

Comment: no there is no path issue check the images that i had attached it is working in css.php but it is not working in index.php